# Cocoa Emacs print-buffer

Tags: macos, emacs, printing

In Carbon Emacs, I was able to call M-x print-buffer and an OS-X Print Dialog appeared, letting me choose my printer.

Now that I've switched to Cocoa Emacs 23.1, the print-buffer command does not behave the same way. It ends up sending the job directly to the printer, using the last selected printer (which might not even be available).

Is there a way to get the OS X Print Dialog to appear before printing in Cocoa Emacs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm also interested in this. I found Mac Print Mode on emacswiki:

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MacPrintMode

I haven't had a chance to try it out yet, but sounds like what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks Eric! I'll give it a shot and update this question w/ results.